# Working with more than one text box and drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a drop-down and text box for time calculation of a specific day, in the text box the duration is entered, based on which the timeslot is generated in the drop-down. This works fine for one text box and one drop-down but for multiple text-boxes and drop-downs, it takes the same value assigned to the first text-box. So,How to get the multiple values for each day and what is the mistake. And to display multiple text-boxes and drop-down I have used ng-repeat. Please do help me , if anything is wrong please correct me. Thank you :)

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="field in fields" name="slotSelection">
<td align="center">
<ion-checkbox ng-model="field.checked">{{field.name}} </ion-checkbox>
</td>
<td>
<select ng-model="time" ng-options="time for time in timeslots">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" ng-model="interval" ng-blur="setTimeSlots(interval)">
</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.fields = [{ id: 1, name: 'Sunday' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Monday' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Tuesday' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Wednesday' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Thursday' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Friday' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Sunday' }]

      $scope.setTimeSlots = function (interval) {
         var startingTime = moment().hours(8).minutes(0);
         $scope.timeslots = [];
         for(var i=0; i < interval; i++){
         $scope.intervals=60;
            $scope.timeslots.push(startingTime.add($scope.intervals,'minute').format("h:mm"));
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `timeslots` to each `field` in the `fields` scope property and you can pass the current `field` to `setTimeSlot` method as shown,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="interval" ng-blur="setTimeSlots(interval, field)">
```

Then in the `setTimeSlots`, push the time slots as shown below,

```
$scope.setTimeSlots = function(interval, field) {
    var startingTime = moment().hours(8).minutes(0);
    field.timeslots = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < interval; i++) {
      $scope.intervals = 60;
      field.timeslots.push(startingTime.add($scope.intervals, 'minute').format("h:mm"));
    }
  }
```

Working plunkr [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/J1qt1X7QqDfllC2RwmCP/)

Comment: will I be able to read the whole row when the days are checked??

Comment: What you meant by `days are checked`? The `setTimeSlots` function will always receive interval and the current `field` object from `fields` property

Comment: since there is a check-box , if user wants to display the selected days along with duration and timeslot will I be able  to get it , ie json display `[{'day':Monday, 'duration':3,'selectedSlot:11},{'day':wednesday,'duration':2,'selectedSlot':9}]`